# mvc3 modal dialog with tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-3, tabs, modal-dialog

I have created a modal dialog in my project and I can load the partialview/view  in the modal dialog, problem is on the view I have 3 tabs and each one of them is referencing another partialview. when I click on the tabs it brings the related partialview in the parent page (the page that has the link to the modal dialog) instead of just shifting through the tabs while  inside the modal dialog.
Anyone have experienced this issue before?

I will appreciate any help or similar examples that I can look through.

this is my code
      jQuery(document).ready(function () {

```
        $('.trigger').live('click', function (event)
         { 
              var id = $(this).attr('rel');    
                 var dialogBox = $("<div>");
                       $(dialogBox).dialog({   
                               autoOpen: false,
                               resizable: true,
                               title: 'Test Modal Dialog',
                               modal: true,
                               show: "blind",
                               hide: "blind", 
                               open: function (event, ui) {

                                         $(this).load('<%=Url.Action("action1","controllerName")%>');
                                                                           } 



                                     });  
                                       $(dialogBox).dialog('open');
                                   });
```

and then I have 4 partial views first one is the action1:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<NeboAlertManagement.Models.model>" %>
```

" type="text/javascript">

 " type="text/javascript">

" type="text/javascript">

" type="text/javascript">

```
        <div id="tabContainer">
         <ul id="menu"> 


          <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "action2", "controllername")%></li>
          <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Products", "action3", "controllername")%></li>
          <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Contact Us", "action4", "controllername")%></li>


      <%--    <li><%= Html.RenderPartial("action2")%></li>
          <li><%= Html.RenderPartial("action3")%></li>
          <li><%= Html.RenderPartial( "action4")%></li>--%>


        </ul>
        </div>
        <% } %>
```

and the other three partialviews are simple test views but if it helps I can post them!

Thanks!

Comment: Noticing any JavaScript error?

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand! can you give more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

You should give a 'trigger' class to your links - tabs, so that jquery live can capture them.

```
Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", new { controller = "Home" }, new { @class = "trigger" })
```

and at the top of click handler use

```
 $('.trigger').live('click', function (event)
 { 
     event.preventDefault()
     var uriToLoad = $(this).attr('href');
```

Before loading values into popup - make sure you use the same popup. Because now you create each time new popup. So:

```
// popup already present
if($('#mypopupid').length > 0 && $('#mypopupid').dialog("isOpen")) {
    $('#mypopupid').load(uriToLoad);
} else { // rest of the code - give popup id
  var dialogBox = $('<div id="mypopupid" />')
}
```

If popup is already present use it, if not open new.

Comment: I appreciate your response, I tried it didnt work, when i click on the tab it closes my modal dialog and opens the partial view in the main page, thanks anyways

Comment: I tried the addition and it helped partially that it did not close the dialog and go to the main page anymore but, when I click on the tab it opens another dialog of the same modal dialog (instead of opening the partial view of the clicked tab) , so I end up having several modal dialogs on my page, any idea why this is happening, and thank you for your help!

Comment: Updated version with check whether you have already created popup and it is opened.

Comment: Thanks! I was told that I need to use tabs instead of links in my modal dialog so I kinda swithced my code, But I will try to test this and tag it as answer a bit later